# Integrating apache shiro in springboot application

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, shiro

I am trying to learn spring boot so I got the petclinic open source project:
[petclinic-springboot](https://github.com/spring-petclinic/spring-petclinic-reactjs)
Whcih uses spring boot and mysql database. Now I am trying to integrate the apache shiro in this project but I could not find any tutorial on how to integrate shiro with spring boot and mysql. Any ideas or tutorials on how to start?!

Thank you!

Comment: does this help? https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/07/13/apache-shiro-spring-boot

Comment: I went through this tutorial, it did not really help a lot:(

Comment: Not a tutorial, but here is a sample: https://github.com/apache/shiro/tree/master/samples/spring-boot-web

Comment: Thank you Brian! I ran through this sample from the official shiro github, they explain the very little basic first step only, it was not really helpful:(